# Can I change rabbitmq node name?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have started to run RabbitMQ on EC2 linux.

I'm running a RabbitMQ on default settings, so my RabbitMQ node name is rabbit@{hostname} now and the hostname is default EC2 hostname, `ip-{my IP address}`.

I want to change the node name, if I change the directories and .pid name in `mnesia/` and `rabbitmq.conf` file as `rabbit@newhost`, would it be work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think yes, you can configure any of this parameters using environment variables, it's described on RabbitMQ configuration page https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html

Answer (score 9):

The following is what should be in the `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` file (create it):

```
NODENAME=rabbitNodeName@myServerName
```

Next restart **RabbitMQ**:

```
sudo service rabbitmq-server restart
```

Comment: Does this preserve any persistent messages in durable queues? Or are they lost?

Comment: this didn't work, just tried on my 3.8.x version