# RabbitMQ changed node on reboot, need to change back or merge messages/add node

Tags: rabbitmq

Currently a RabbitMQ server is running on an Ubuntu server and was using node `rabbitmq@ubuntu`. The server needed a reboot, nothing was manually changed, but now the RabbitMQ node is `rabbitmq@Ubuntu`.

`/etc/hostname` has `ubuntu` but the command `hostname` gives `Ubuntu`.

So my guess is RabbitMQ has started a new node based on Ubuntu as hostname, but I can't say what the command 'hostname' returned before the change of RabbitMQ.

There are now two directories in `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia`: `rabbit@ubuntu` and `rabbit@Ubuntu`.

The web management shows the clustername is now 'rabbit@ubuntu'. What the clustername was before the change is not known.

There are several messages we need to parse from the `ubuntu` node and I don't know if that's possible.

Is it possible to add the other node? Or can we change the hostname using the 'hostname' command and let Rabbit automatically change the node? Or can we use the rename method as mentioned at [Rename RabbitMQ node](https://serverfault.com/questions/822967/can-i-change-rabbitmq-node-name)

The main question is how to set the old node back without losing messages?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to stop the rabbit server, change the hostname back to `ubuntu` and restart the service. Messages where still there and could be parsed.